# Moving lines with a duplicate column from a file

Tags: awk

How to move consecutive lines from a 
file that has the elements in a column
identical and appeared once before in a previous
consecutive set of lines in that file.

An example of the input and output would be:
input

```
A 1  M L2
A 2  L L2
A 3  N L2
A 4  M L3
A 5  L L3
A 6  N L3
A 7  M L2
A 8  L L2
A 9  N L2
A 10 M L4
A 11 L L4
A 12 N L4
```

Output:
file1

```
A 1  M L2
A 2  L L2
A 3  N L2
A 4  M L3
A 5  L L3
A 6  N L3
A 10 M L4
A 11 L L4
A 12 N L4
```

file2

```
A 7  M L2
A 8  L L2
A 9  N L2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{if (a[$1,$3,$4]++ == 0) print > "file1"; else print > "file2" }' input
```